# UIViewController with scrollview doesn't scroll

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

On my storyboard I've placed a `UIViewController` that has an image on half it's height and the other half has a `scrollViewController` with other controls in it like labels buttons segments etc.

when running the app, the scroller doesn't scroll, I have user interaction enabled on as well as scrolling enabled and show vertical indicator.

ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
//sview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
sview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4500, 320);
[sview setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `contentSize` of your scrollview. Otherwise it won't scroll.

Comment: how can I set that from storyboard, where I want to "design" what it contains

Comment: You can design the contents of your scroll view in the storyboard. I assume that you already did that. However, you still have to tell you scrollView how large its contents are programmatically. If you have static content in you scrollView just add the following line to viewDidLoad: scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(yourWidth, yourHeight)